# How to implement tab view in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, tabs, android-actionbar

**In my windows application, I want to implement tab view like android tab view.**

For reference please see the below image.

[image]

How should I Implement that in Windows phone 7 or 8.
I'm looking forward for your reply.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the Windows Phone 7 SDK doesn't have a TabControl. It is a quite useful component already available in Silverlight and although it doesn't quite follow the Metro style.
[Using the TabControl on Windows Phone 7](http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/using-tabcontrol-windows-phone) gives you better idea. Here is good example using tab control in wp7

```
<ListBox x:Name="lstBoxRss"  SelectionChanged="lstBoxRss_SelectionChanged_1">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,5">
                        <TextBlock x:Name="txtblkLink"  Text="{Binding Title}" Foreground="Blue" TextDecorations="Underline" TextWrapping="Wrap" Tap="txtblkLink_Tap" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding PubDate}" Foreground="Red"/>
                        <TextBlock  Text="{Binding Description}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="Black"/>
                        <Button x:Name="btnOne" Content="ButtonOne" Click="btnOne_Click_1"/>
                        <Button x:Name="btnTwo" Content="Button Two" Click="btnTwo_Click_1"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>

//Code behind
 private void lstBoxRss_SelectionChanged_1(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
          //Listbox selection change
          // do your work
          if(lstBoxRss.SelectedIndex==-1)
          return;
        }

  private void btnOne_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
           //First button click 
           //Do your work
        }

        private void btnTwo_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
          //button  two click 
          //Do your work
         }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can we have expandable listbox in windows phone 7 or 8 like in android.

Comment: @user2636874 yes there is ExpanderView in windows phone. http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/windows-phone-toolkit-expanderview-in-depth-part2-data-binding   http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/windows-phone-toolkit-expanderview-in-depth-part1-key-concepts-and-api go with links

Comment: and one more question is i have listbox item with some text views and some 2 buttons. So how should I do the two buttons clickable so that for each button i have separate functionality to do. And if user click on the list item not on the buttons then i have to do another functionality. Could you please tell me how to get all the fields in the list box item and make clickable whatever field we want.

Answer (score 0):

There is no TabControl in the Windows Phone SDK 8. The closest equivalent is a Pivot control. You can put a row of clickable text or icons at the top of a Pivot and make it operate like a tab bar.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpdevelop/thread/1baf74fa-0ddd-4226-a02d-a7fc9f80374d

Pivot control instead of a TabControl for the WindowsPhone. the Pivot control follows the design guidelines for the phone and looks and feels much better.
For Windows phone 7 visit this Link:

http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Tab_Control_in_Qt_and_Windows_Phone